# Binding NSTokenField to array controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, nsarray, nstokenfield

I have an array controller and a token field for data entry.
I can't find a way to use the token field to bind a tokenized text to the array controller.

The problem is when I use a token field delegate it's returning an `NSArray` instead of my entity's attribute with `NSString` format, and when running my app if I use this token field, I have an error that shows me the incompatible data mode (attribute accepts `NSString` instead of `NSArray`).

In fact, I can handle the token field to show me the token parameters but I can't handle binding of token field into the data array!

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: did you solve this problem? I have the same here, and i'm trying to use a value transformer, but I don't know how to set it up.

Comment: @Mario, Nope ! I finally changed back to NSTextField's autocompletion and I am Done now !

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I believe I have an answer and would like to contribute it since bindings for a token field's "value" aren't documented well.  In fact, the Apple Documentation is misleading.

If all you want is an array of strings stored in core data and no dealing with `representedObject` or token field delegates, you can actually do everything in the XIB and your xcdatamodel.

The first step in switching your core data entity's NSString attribute to an attribute that you can bind to the token field. You need to make the attribute a transformable type.  Call it `tokenStringArray`. You're done with the data model.  (And any code that accesses this attribute should now expect an array of strings.)

The token field's value binding wants to be connected to a controller that can deliver a single entity with the controller key, and that single entity has a model key path that delivers an array of strings. So if your array controller is selecting a single entity, you would have `selection` for the controller key and `tokenStringArray` for the model key path. Select "Continuously Updates Value" or saves might not persist immediately.

That's it.  Having bound the transformable `tokenStringArray` attribute to the token field's value, the user's changes to the token field are persisted.

[For what it's worth, I personally have an object controller bound to a single entity. To bind the token field to a core data attribute, it seems that some sort of controller must intermediate, so for me, it's object controller.  If you have a table where the user's selection of an entity should populate the token field, then you'd use an array controller. The token field can't edit an array controller's `arrangedObjects` -- it can only take and deliver an array from a **single** object.]